# Bot deployment failing

Tags: azure, botframework

I am creating a Web App Bot. After specifying all the necessary details like resource-group, storage, app-insights and their locations I click create. But deployments after a couple of minutes. I am getting following error:

> At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list
> deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug
> for usage details.
>
> code: **DeploymentFailed**
>
> DeveloperAppInsightsApplicationId: Developer App Insights Application
> ID is not a valid GUID.
>
> code: **InvalidBotData**

Attaching image of the error:

[image]

This is not the first time I am creating bot. I have setup quite a few bots earlier successfully. I don't even know what info I can share here.

Comment: As far as I know, App Insights Application ID should be generated by Azure when we create it on Azure, perhaps something wrong temporarily with generating AppId while Azure is creating resources for you. Do you try to deploy the resources to another resource group or specify another available location from **Application Insights Location** options?

Comment: @Fei Han That is problem. The stage where I am getting error, I don't need to do or specify anything. I anyway always tried with a new Resource Group. And yeah I also tried with different location. I hope this is something temporary.

Comment: I think it should be a temporary issue.

Comment: Hi Master Chief! A client reported a similar error ("Developer App Insights Application ID is not a valid GUID.") to our team yesterday; I'm currently waiting for a response from incident management, and will post an answer as soon as they reply!

Comment: Hi Master Chief! Me again! There is a current ongoing issue concerning this error. The incident management team is correcting it at the moment, and there is a hotfix in place. Can you try to deploy bot again and post what happens?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes, Yep I reployed and now it is working fine. I will close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a temporary glitch on Azure. Once it got fixed my problem got resolved.